# escape pipe( | ) character inside table. in Github pages

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

In my github page, the escape charecters not working currectly.

https://alirezanet.github.io/Gridify/
[image]

but its working currectly in [github](https://github.com/Alirezanet/Gridify)
[image]

if i remove these backslashes from MD file entire table will break in github,

how can i fix this?

```
| Name                  | Operator | Usage example                                             |
| --------------------- | -------- | --------------------------------------------------------- |
| Equal                 | `==`     | `"FieldName==Value"`                                      |
| AND - &&              | `,`      | `"FirstName==Value , LastName==Value2"`                   |
| OR - \|\|             | `\|`     | `"FirstName==Value \| LastName==Value2"`                  |
| Parenthesis           | `()`     | `"( FirstName=*Jo,Age<<30) \| ( FirstName!=Hn,Age>>30 )"` |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<code>&#124;</code>
```

in replacement of `|`

Comment: code tag ..! i totally forgot that option exists. thank you.